# About var/const, why this code will work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Open dev console (or in node.js), enter the following code by sequence:

```
a = 1
var a = 2
const a = 3
```

[image: screenshot1]

As you can see it works, but if you enter all the code at once, you will get an error, which I think is more reasonable [image: screenshot2]

I guess the only difference is hoisting, if you input all the code at once, it will be treated as:

```
var a
a = 1
a = 2
const a = 3
```

But I don't understand why it works when you enter line by line, also if you skip the first line, you get an error as expected

[image]

Comment: Interesting behavior! You're probably exposing some specific behavior of the console environment.

Comment: @AndyRay I tried in node.js and different browser, I get the same result

Comment: I could imagine that in the first case the `var` is actually ignored because there is already a property on the global object with name `a` (because of `a = 1`). Because of that there isn't actually any information that `var a` was declared. As you point out in the second case, `var a` is hoisted, therefore processed before `a = 1` happens, so it's not ignored. But that's speculation, console / REPL environments might do weird things.

Comment: For what it's worth, my FF does throw an redeclaration error even when passed line by line. (chrome bug ?)

Answer (score 1):

In global scope of the environment a variable can be assigned and declared irrespective of the type, therefore when you enter following code in sequence, it works.

```
z = 1
var z = 2
const z = 3
```

value of z is 3 now

Now lets say we execute all this at once

```
    z = 4;  var z = 5;  const z = 6;
```

value of z is still 3

the interpreter in this case will throw error because here it will try to execute all the above statement once as a block and now it has found multiple declaration for 'z' and thus will throw an error for the whole block and will not execute even the first part i.e `z = 4;`

the statement where everything is executed at once is equivalent to

```
(function foo(){ z = 4; var z = 5; const z = 6;  })();
```

Comment: You can notice one thing.. if we use dev tool to define variable 'a' it appends to window object and if you add 'const a' it doesn't add to window object 

e.g. var a = 2;
you fill find window.a value as 2

and you enter 
const a = 3;
you still notice that window.a value remain same means 2.

Comment: So basically if placed all in one line that is a block scope and const z cannot change making anything else as z invalid. But if z is declared on separate lines, each line is considered it's own scope so const value doesn't apply to them?